# Example of a function that has the Luzin $n$-property and is not absolutely continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, examples-counterexamples, absolute-continuity

The Banach–Zaretsky theorem ([page 196](https://books.google.com/books?id=o928IAmynmoC&pg=PA196)) says that a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation is absolutely continuous if and only if

$$E\subset I \text{ has zero Lebesgue measure }\Rightarrow f(E) \text{ has zero Lebesgue measure }\;\;[\#]$$

I would like see an example of a function that satisfies $[\#]$ but is not absolutely continuous.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

The theorem says that continuity, bounded variation (BV), and # (Property N) imply absolute continuity. Here's how it fails if we have two of the properties:

**BV & Property N**

Let  $f(x) = \operatorname{sign} x$. The range is finite, so $f(E)$ always has zero Lebesgue measure. But $f$ is not absolutely continuous.

**Continuity & Property N**

Let $f(x) = x\sin (1/x)$, $f(0)=0$. Property $N$ follows from the fact that $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $\mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}$. But $f$ is not BV, so is not absolutely continuous.

**Continuity & BV**

Let $f$ be the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).